# vxworks update time & get it to hold after a reboot

Tags: c, time, vxworks

I am trying to have my device reboot and the time be the same after a reboot.  How do I achieve this from usrAppInit.c?  I can change the time but it doesn't stay as a "gettime #1" on a reboot.  What am I missing?  Thank you for your time.  I have tried this soo far and failed...

```
    struct timespec timep;
    struct tm *ptr_tm_GMT;

    if (clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, &timep) == 0)
    {
        (void)ipcom_printf("%s[%d]  gettime #1: %lx.%lx, %s\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__,
                  timep.tv_sec, timep.tv_nsec, ipcom_ctime((time_t*)&timep.tv_sec));

    timep.tv_sec = (time_t)(1674065500UL);
        timep.tv_nsec = 0;
        ptr_tm_GMT = gmtime((time_t*)&timep);   // out *tm    in *time_t
    vxbRtcSet(ptr_tm_GMT);
        if (clock_settime (CLOCK_REALTIME, &timep) == 0)
        {
        //vxbRtcGet(ptr_tm_GMT);
        if (clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, &timep) == 0)
            {
                (void)ipcom_printf("%s[%d]  gettime #2: %lx.%lx, %s\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__,
                        timep.tv_sec, timep.tv_nsec, ipcom_ctime((time_t*)&timep.tv_sec));
        }
        else
        {
                (void)ipcom_printf("%s[%d]  ERROR:  clock_gettime\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        }
        }
        else
    {
            (void)ipcom_printf("%s[%d]  ERROR:  clock_settime\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    }
    }
    else
    {
        (void)ipcom_printf("%s[%d]  ERROR:  clock_settime\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    }
```

I have tried to use clockLib functions which doesn't persist over a reboot.  I would like to learn how to use code to permanently set the time where that time holds across a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This will be dependent on the hardware you run on.

For the time to be persistent across a reboot, you typically need Real Time Clock (RTC) hardware on the board.  These are typically battery backed and will keep time even if the hardware gets powered off.

Without one of those, it is unlikely you can keep the time across reset.

With an RTC present, you need to have an appropriate device driver or some code that on reset queries the current time and sets the system clock (assuming it's not done already by the RTC device driver).